# Unique constraint across two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called friends with the following structure:

```
id
user_id
friend_id
```

and I want the rows to be unique so for example:

```
1, 6, 12
2, 6, 12
```

would break! I've achieved this with: `ALTER TABLE friends ADD UNIQUE INDEX user_id_friend_id (user_id, friend_id);`

BUT I also want the following to **not** be possible

```
1, 6, 12
2, 12, 6
```

How do I do that? I tried doing the same statement but with the fields reversed but it didn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using? Sometimes this is easy, sometimes it's not. Depends on the database.

Comment: I have the constraint in the code for my app. But I'd like to do it in the DB as well. Take it MySQL is rubbish for this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use triggers to ensure that `user_id <= friend_id`, this with the unique constraint will achieve what you want. You'll need an insert and update trigger like this:

```
Create Trigger
  Friends_ins_check 
Before Insert On
  Friends
For Each Row
Begin
  If new.user_id > new.friend_id Then
    Set @temp = new.user_id;
    Set new.user_id = new.friend_id;
    Set new.friend_id = @temp;
  End If;
End
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c1d0)

Comment: if someone is confused by `For Each Row` like i was, here is a post clarifying the behaviour:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374151/how-does-for-each-row-work-in-triggers-in-mysql?