# How does "for each row" work in triggers in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In mysql triggers, when I do a "after update" on table `A` and then use "for each row", will it run the body of the trigger for each row in `A` every time a row gets updated in `A`, or is it saying to apply the trigger to every row in `A` and then if a row gets updated, it will only run the body code for that updated row only?

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

***`FOR EACH ROW`*** means ***for each of the matched row*** that gets either ***updated*** or ***deleted***.

Trigger body won't loop through the entire table data unless there is a where condition in the query.

A working example is demonstrated below:

**Create sample tables**:

```
drop table if exists tbl_so_q23374151; 
create table tbl_so_q23374151 ( i int, v varchar(10) );

-- set test data
insert into tbl_so_q23374151 
values (1,'one'),(2,'two' ),(3,'three'),(10,'ten'),(11,'eleven');

-- see current data in table**:  
select * from tbl_so_q23374151;
+------+--------+
| i    | v      |
+------+--------+
|    1 | one    |
|    2 | two    |
|    3 | three  |
|   10 | ten    |
|   11 | eleven |
+------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Sample table to record loop count in trigger body**:

```
-- let us record, loop count of trigger, in a table
drop table if exists tbl_so_q23374151_rows_affected; 
create table tbl_so_q23374151_rows_affected( i int );

select count(*) as rows_affected from tbl_so_q23374151_rows_affected;
+---------------+
| rows_affected |
+---------------+
|             0 |
+---------------+
```

**Define a *delete* trigger**:

```
drop trigger if exists trig_bef_del_on_tbl_so_q23374151;
delimiter //
create trigger trig_bef_del_on_tbl_so_q23374151 before delete on tbl_so_q23374151
  for each row begin
    set @cnt = if(@cnt is null, 1, (@cnt+1));

    /* for cross checking save loop count */
    insert into tbl_so_q23374151_rows_affected values ( @cnt );
  end;
//

delimiter ;
```

**Now, test a *delete* operation**:

```
delete from tbl_so_q23374151 where i like '%1%';

-- now let us see what the loop count was
select @cnt as 'cnt';
+------+
| cnt  |
+------+
|    3 |
+------+
```

**Now, check the trigger effect on main table**:

```
-- now let us see the table data
select * from tbl_so_q23374151;
+------+-------+
| i    | v     |
+------+-------+
|    2 | two   |
|    3 | three |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select count(*) as rows_affected from tbl_so_q23374151_rows_affected;
+---------------+
| rows_affected |
+---------------+
|             3 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @omega: Let me hope you got the answer right. [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 11):

Literally - mysql will run your trigger code for every row which was affected by the SQL statement.

And NOT for each row in table A by itself.

Answer (score 5):

It's just a MySQL syntax quirk and it's virtually meaningless. MySQL triggers *require* the `FOR EACH ROW` syntax. You'll get a syntax error without it. They work exactly the same as Standard SQL (e.g., SQLite) triggers without `FOR EACH ROW`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. FOR EACH ROW is redundant. In other databases, it is understood, but Mysql needs us to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger is not applied to each row, it just say to execute trigger body for each affected table row.

`FOR EACH ROW` says when it should be executed, not where create trigger.