# How to access "INSERTED" values in a MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

How can I access the the `INSERTED` table's values in a trigger?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO sales (sku, qty) 
VALUES
(1001, 5), //I need these values in the trigger
(1002, 1)
...
```

This is my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_sales_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON sales 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE products
    SET NEW.qty = OLD.qty - INSERTED.qty
    WHERE sku = INSERTED.sku;

END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Note that `sales.sku` is a foreign key for the `products` table.

SQL Server has the `INSERTED` keyword, which doesn't seem to work for MySQL.

### Answer:

`NEW.qty` references the `qty` on the table that the trigger is set on, **not** the table that is being updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_sales_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON sales 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    UPDATE products
    SET qty = qty - NEW.qty
    WHERE sku = NEW.sku;

END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
INSERT INTO sales (sku, qty) 
VALUES
(1001, 5), //I need these values in the trigger
(1002, 1)
...
```

I believe you want this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_sales_insert AFTER INSERT ON sales 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE products
    SET qty = qty - NEW.qty
    WHERE sku = NEW.sku;
END;
```

References:

- [MySQL 8: 24.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- [How to program a MySQL trigger to insert row into another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753878/)
- [How does "for each row" work in triggers in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374151/)

Comment: is it possible in mysql to join on the NEW, like you can join on INSERTED in SQL server...so not to do it one at a time?

Comment: It all makes sense now.  I thought `NEW.qty` was referencing the products table and not the sales table.  Thanks!